# GW gauge choice shortcut

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, gauge-invariance

When solving the linearised Einstein field equations for gravitational waves, we define the trace reversed metric $\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}$ for which we write the coordinate transformations $x^\mu \rightarrow x^\mu + \xi^\mu$ and choose to cancel the divergence $\partial^\mu \bar{h}_{\mu\nu}$ (in Lorenz gauge). We can further fix the $\xi _\mu$ to cancel the trace of $\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}$ and get the TT gauge.

My question : is it possible to get the same answer without using the trace reversed metric ?

If I have for the metric perturbation :

$h_{\mu\nu} \rightarrow h_{\mu\nu} + \partial_\mu\xi_\nu + \partial_\nu\xi_\mu$,

for which I can write the divergence and trace, and choose to cancel them as :

$\partial^\mu h_{\mu\nu} \rightarrow \partial^\mu h_{\mu\nu} + \Box \xi_\nu + \partial^\mu \partial_\nu \xi_\mu = 0$

$ h \rightarrow h + 2 \partial^\mu \xi_\mu = 0$,

then I have already two conditions for the $\xi_\mu$ giving :

$\partial^\mu \xi_\mu = -\frac{1}{2} h$

$\Box \xi_\nu = \frac{1}{2} \partial_\nu h - \partial^\mu h_{\mu\nu}$,

and reproducing the TT gauge.

I feel like I am missing something...

Cheers,

Comment: You have 5 equations for 4 components of the gauge vector. How do you show that you can solve this seemingly overdetermined set of equations?